# Knowing which CPE is opened in Apache UIMA CPE Configurator

Tags: windows-7, apache-uima

In [Apache UIMA](https://uima.apache.org/), when a [Collection Processing Engine (CPE)](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.1.0-incubating/docs/html/tutorials_and_users_guides/tutorials_and_users_guides.html#ugr.tug.cpe) is opened in the [CPE Configurator](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.1.0-incubating/docs/html/tutorials_and_users_guides/tutorials_and_users_guides.html#ugr.tug.cpe.cpe_configurator), how can I see which CPE file was used?

I use Apache UIMA 2.6.0 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.